# ASP NET - C#: Access controls by Id

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, controls

In my ASP.Net project; I'm using C# as behind code.

One of my project functions creates some text boxes dynamically, according to user's needs. Each textbox has a different Id.

My question is how can I access those textboxes by Id?

Let say that were created 5 textboxes, how can I edit the code of specifically one of them?

Bellow is the actual code that I use to generate those textboxes:

```
int name_id = 1;
foreach (WebApplication5.ServiceReference1.ClientData client in Clients)
{
    TextBox1 = new TextBox();
    TextBox1.ID = name_id.ToString();
    TextBox1.Style["Position"] = "Absolute";
    TextBox1.Style["Top"] = y + "px";
    TextBox1.Style["Left"] = x + "px";
    TextBox1.Text = client.descricao;
    Form.Controls.Add(TextBox1);

    name_id++;
    x = x + 10;
    y = y + 10;
}
```

Comment: You should add these controls to a [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx) or [PlaceHolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) instead of directly to the Form. On this way it's simplier to change the layout.

Comment: Do you want to access them from the Client or Server side?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this in code behind;

```
TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)FindControl(name_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBox tb = Form.FindControl(TextBox1.ID) as TextBox
```

Only like this, the reson why you can't access by ID directly is they absent at *.designer.cs.